# Not able to display fetch location into Textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am trying to fetch location in background and trying to show that location into textfield but I don't understand how to do that.
in my home screen there is one dialogue box. in that dialogue box there are 3 dropdown list(country, state,city). user can manually select the location or else by click on get my location icon.
after clicking on current location icon, it should fetch current location and display every thing into those three dropdown. I am able to get the current address but unfortunately, I am not able to display that country, state and city into dropdownlists.

My location page

```
class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CityBasedModel? model;
  final bool isDialogBox;
  final Function(CityBasedModel? e, String? address)? onChangeValue;
  const LocationPage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.model,
      this.isDialogBox = true,
      this.onChangeValue})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocationPage> createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  LocationData? locationData;
  bool isLoading = false;
  String? errorMsg;
  CityBasedModel cityStateModel = CityBasedModel();
  List<CountryModel> countryModels = [];
  List<StateModel> stateModels = [];
  List<CityModel> cityModels = [];
  final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  Location currentLocation = Location();
  final TextEditingController nameEditController = TextEditingController();
  double? l1, l2;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.model != null) {
      cityStateModel = widget.model!;
    }
    initAsync();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    addressController.dispose();
    nameEditController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  fetchCountries() {
    countryModels = CountryStateServices.countries;
    setState(() {});
  }

  onChangeLocation() {
    if (widget.onChangeValue != null) {
      widget.onChangeValue!(cityStateModel,
          addressController.text.isNotEmpty ? addressController.text : null);
    }
  }

  initAsync() async {
    await fetchCountries();
    if (cityStateModel.id != null) {
      await fetchState(cityStateModel.countryId!);
      fetchCities(
          countryCode: cityStateModel.countryCode!.toString(),
          stateName: cityStateModel.stateName!.toString(),
          id: cityStateModel.id);
    }
  }

  isMountedState(Function callback) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        callback();
      });
    }
  }

  fetchState(String id) {
    stateModels = CountryStateServices.fetchStateByCountryId(countryId: id);

    setState(() {});
  }

  fetchCities(
      {String? countryCode,
      String? stateName,
      String? search,
      String? id,
      bool showLoading = true}) async {
    if (showLoading) {
      isMountedState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }
    final res = await LocationServices.getCities(
        id: id, countryCode: countryCode, stateName: stateName, search: search);
    res.fold((l) {
      isMountedState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        errorMsg = getErrorMessage(l);
      });
    }, (r) {
      isMountedState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        cityModels = r;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool isDialogBox = widget.isDialogBox;

    if (isDialogBox) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 450,
        width: .90.sw,
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            if (UserServices.user?.city == null) {
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Center(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w, vertical: 20.h),
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w, vertical: 20.h),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(child: formWidget(l1, l2)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return formWidget(l1, l2);
    }
  }

  Widget formWidget(double? l1, double? l2) {
    final bool isDialogBox = widget.isDialogBox;
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Visibility(
              visible: isDialogBox &&
                  (UserServices.user!.name == null ||
                      UserServices.user!.name!.isEmpty),
              child: paddingFun(
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Name",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: CustomColors.blackColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.h,
                    ),
                    TextFormFieldCustom(
                      controller: nameEditController,
                      hintText: 'Enter your name',
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 3) {
                          return "Enter your valid name";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
          paddingFun(
            DropDownButtonSearch<CountryModel?>(
              items: countryModels,
              selectedItem: cityStateModel.countryId != null
                  ? CountryModel(
                      countyCode: cityStateModel.countryCode,
                      id: cityStateModel.countryId != null
                          ? int.parse(cityStateModel.countryId!)
                          : null,
                      name: cityStateModel.countryName)
                  : null,
              hasLocation: locationData != null,
              onChanged: (value) async {
                cityStateModel = cityStateModel.copyWith(
                    countryCode: value?.countyCode,
                    countryName: value?.name,
                    countryId: value?.id.toString(),
                    stateCode: null,
                    stateName: null,
                    stateId: "-1",
                    id: "-1",
                    name: null);
                await fetchState(cityStateModel.countryId!);
                onChangeLocation();
                isMountedState(() {});
              },
              label: 'Country',
              itemAsString: (CountryModel? model) {
                return model != null ? model.name ?? "Select" : "Select";
              },
            ),
          ),
          paddingFun(
            DropDownButtonSearch<StateModel?>(
              items: stateModels,
              hasLocation: locationData != null,
              selectedItem: cityStateModel.stateId != null &&
                      cityStateModel.stateId != "-1"
                  ? StateModel(
                      stateCode: cityStateModel.stateCode,
                      countryId: cityStateModel.countryId,
                      countryName: cityStateModel.countryName,
                      countyCode: cityStateModel.countryCode,
                      id: int.parse(cityStateModel.stateId!),
                      name: cityStateModel.stateName)
                  : null,
              onChanged: (value) async {
                cityStateModel = cityStateModel.copyWith(
                    id: "-1",
                    name: null,
                    stateCode: value?.stateCode,
                    stateName: value?.name,
                    stateId: value?.id.toString());
                await fetchCities(
                  id: cityStateModel.stateId,
                );
                onChangeLocation();
                isMountedState(() {});
              },
              label: 'State',
              itemAsString: (StateModel? value) {
                return value != null ? value.name ?? "Select" : "Select";
              },
            ),
          ),
          paddingFun(
            DropDownButtonSearch<CityModel?>(
              items: cityModels,
              hasLocation: locationData != null,
              selectedItem:
                  cityStateModel.id != null && cityStateModel.id != "-1"
                      ? CityModel(
                          id: cityStateModel.id!,
                          name: cityStateModel.name,
                          countyCode: cityStateModel.countryCode!,
                          stateCode: cityStateModel.stateCode,
                          stateId: cityStateModel.stateId,
                          stateName: cityStateModel.stateName,
                          countryId: cityStateModel.countryId,
                          countryName: cityStateModel.countryCode,
                        )
                      : null,
              onChanged: (value) {
                cityStateModel =
                    cityStateModel.copyWith(id: value?.id, name: value?.name);
                onChangeLocation();
                isMountedState(() {});
              },
              itemAsString: (CityModel? value) {
                return value != null ? value.name ?? "Select" : "Select";
              },
              label: 'City',
            ),
          ),
          GetCurrentLocation(
            addressData: (
                {city,
                countryCode,
                stateName,
                address,
                required latlong}) async {
              try {
                isMountedState(() {
                  errorMsg = null;
                });
                await fetchCities(
                    search: city,
                    stateName: stateName,
                    countryCode: countryCode,
                    showLoading: false);

                cityStateModel = cityStateModel.copyWith(
                    latitude: latlong[0].toString(),
                    longitude: latlong[1].toString());
                List<CityModel> cityModelSearch = cityModels
                    .where((element) => element.name.toString() == "")
                    .toList();
                if (cityModelSearch.isNotEmpty) {
                  CityModel cityModel = cityModelSearch.first;
                  cityStateModel = cityStateModel.copyWith(
                    id: cityModel.id,
                    name: cityModel.name,
                    stateCode: cityModel.stateCode,
                    countryCode: cityModel.countyCode,
                    stateId: cityModel.stateId,
                    stateName: cityModel.stateName,
                    countryName: cityModel.countryName,
                    countryId: cityModel.countryId,
                  );
                  addressController.text = address ?? '';
                  fetchState(cityModel.countryId!);
                }
                onChangeLocation();
              } catch (e) {
                isMountedState(() {
                  errorMsg = e.toString();
                });
              } finally {
                isMountedState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          if (isLoading)
            const Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 16,
                ),
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: CustomColors.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (errorMsg != null)
            Center(
              child: Text(
                errorMsg!,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          if (isDialogBox)
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          if (isDialogBox)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomRoundedButton(
                  height: 30.h,
                  onTap: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      try {
                        isMountedState(() {
                          isLoading = true;
                        });
                        await UserServices.setCityModel(cityStateModel);
                        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                          'city_id': cityStateModel.id,
                          'state_id': cityStateModel.stateId,
                          'country_id': cityStateModel.countryId,
                          'latLong': cityStateModel.toStringLatLong(),
                        };
                        // if (nameEditController.text.isNotEmpty && isDialogBox) {
                        //   data['name'] = nameEditController.text;
                        // }
                        await UserServices.updateUser(user: data).then((value) {
                          value.fold((l) => throw (l),
                              (r) => UserServices.reFetchUser());
                        });
                        if (isDialogBox) {
                          BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context)
                              .add(UpdatePromotionHome());
                        }
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      } catch (e) {
                        isMountedState(() {
                          errorMsg = e.toString();
                        });
                      } finally {
                        if (mounted) {
                          isMountedState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  width: 60.w,
                  isEnable: isEnable(),
                  child: Text(
                    "Submit",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  paddingFun(child) {
    if (widget.isDialogBox) {
      return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16,
            vertical: 0,
          ),
          child: child);
    } else {
      return customPadding(vertical: 5, child);
    }
  }

  bool isEnable() {
    if (cityStateModel.id != null &&
        cityStateModel.stateId != null &&
        cityStateModel.countryId != null &&
        cityStateModel.longitude != null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class DropDownListLocation<t> extends StatelessWidget {
  final String dropDownText;
  final t? initialValue;
  final String Function(t) itemAsString;
  final List<t> items;
  final Future<List<t>> Function(String? value)? asyncItems;
  final String helperText;
  final Function(t?)? onChanged;
  final String? Function(t?)? validator;
  final double height;
  final bool searchOption;

  const DropDownListLocation(
      {Key? key,
      required this.dropDownText,
      this.initialValue,
      required this.items,
      this.onChanged,
      this.validator,
      required this.helperText,
      this.height = 500,
      this.searchOption = false,
      required this.itemAsString,
      this.asyncItems})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 65.h,
      child: DropdownSearch<t>(
        validator: validator,
        popupProps: PopupProps.modalBottomSheet(
          showSearchBox: searchOption,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: height.h,
          ),
          containerBuilder: (context, child) {
            return Container(
              height: height.h,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: CustomColors.peachColor,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        dropDownText,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                              color: CustomColors.greyFont,
                              fontSize: 14.sp,
                            ),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 30.h,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: child,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          /*itemBuilder: (context, item, isSelected) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                itemAsString(item),
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
            );
          },*/
        ),

        //items: items,
        dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: helperText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.sp,
                color: CustomColors.greyFont,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            fillColor: CustomColors.peachColor,
            filled: true,
            contentPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        items: items,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        selectedItem: initialValue,
        itemAsString: itemAsString,
        asyncItems: asyncItems,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And this is the class for getting current location in the app**

```
class GetCurrentLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function(
      {String? city,
      String? countryCode,
      String? stateName,
      String? address,
      required List<double> latlong})? addressData;
  const GetCurrentLocation({
    Key? key,
    this.text = "Get my current location",
    this.addressData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GetCurrentLocation> createState() => _GetCurrentLocationState();
}

class _GetCurrentLocationState extends State<GetCurrentLocation> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return customPadding(InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
        try {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = true;
          });
          List<double> latLong = [];
          final res = await LocationServices.getCurrentLocation();
          var getErrorInLocation = false;
          res.fold(
              (l) => setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                    throw (l);
                  }), (loc) async {
            latLong = [loc.latitude!, loc.longitude!];
          });

          String? locality = "";
          String? locationName = "";
          String? subLocality = "";
          String? country = "";
          String? postalCode = "";
          String? stateName = "";
          String? countryCode = "";
          final data = await LocationServices.getAddressFromLocation(
              lat: latLong[0], long: latLong[1]);
          data.fold((l) {
            locality = null;
            locationName = null;
            subLocality = null;
            country = null;
            postalCode = null;
            countryCode = null;
            stateName = null;
          }, (r) {
            locality = r.locality!;
            locationName = r.name!;
            subLocality = r.subLocality!;
            country = r.country!;
            postalCode = r.postalCode!;
            countryCode = r.isoCountryCode!;
            stateName = r.administrativeArea!;
          });

           //here I get the location and I can see that location into my 
           //console with msg: "Successfully fetch location", this toast
          showSnackBar(
              isSuccess: true,
              msg: "Successfully fetch location",
              context: context);
          await widget.addressData!(
              latlong: latLong,
              stateName: stateName,
              address: !getErrorInLocation
                  ? "$locationName $locality $subLocality $country $postalCode"
                  : null,
              countryCode: !getErrorInLocation ? countryCode : null,
              city: !getErrorInLocation ? locality : null);
        } on LocationPermissionFailure {
          CustomDialogs.showLocationErrorDialog(
              context,
              "Access to your location is required to provide the best user experience and features in our app. Without location permission, we are unable to show nearby locations, provide accurate weather updates, or personalize your experience. Please grant location permission to continue using our app and access all its features",
              "Location permission denied",
              11,
              "Enable location permission from app settings");
        } catch (e) {
          showSnackBar(
              isSuccess: false,
              msg: "Unable to fetch location",
              context: context);
          log(e.toString());
        } finally {
          isLoading = false;
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.location_on,
                color: CustomColors.primaryColor,
                size: 30.h,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Text(
                widget.text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: CustomColors.greyFont,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: isLoading,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 30.h,
              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: CustomColors.primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: whats inside LocationServices class?  are you using any package?

Comment: "not getting the current location when i click on get location" That is a huge bunch of code. Surely, you have narrowed down the problem a bit by now? Can you tell us what you found, what line is not behaving like you expect it to behave?